# Using AsyncTask to display web service data in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

Hı,

When I click the button, I am getting data from the web service and post it in listview but I don't want to click the button.When I open the program,first listview is loading and then it show me the data.

Here is my code ( This code is work )

```
package com.example.karayel.wcf;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService/AllUserName";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "AllUserName";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:50006/WCFService2/Service.svc?wsdl";
    String[] userNames = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                            envelope.bodyOut = request;
                            envelope.dotNet = true;
                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                            HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                            userNames = new String[result.getPropertyCount()];
                            for(int i=0;i<result.getPropertyCount();i++){
                                userNames[i]=result.getPropertyAsString(i);
                            }
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    //(A) adım
                                    ListView listemiz=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

                                    //(B) adım
                                    ArrayAdapter<String> veriAdaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                            (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, userNames);

                                    //(C) adım
                                    listemiz.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                networkThread.start();
            }
        });
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I wanna rewrite the code using AsyncTask.How can I do that ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService/AllUserName";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "AllUserName";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:50006/WCFService2/Service.svc?wsdl";
    String[] userNames = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new AsyncTask<Void , Void, String[]>(){

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.bodyOut = request;
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                userNames = new String[result.getPropertyCount()];
                for(int i=0;i<result.getPropertyCount();i++){
                    userNames[i]=result.getPropertyAsString(i);
                }
                return userNames;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
                 //(A) adım
                ListView listemiz=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

                //(B) adım
                ArrayAdapter<String> veriAdaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, result);

                //(C) adım
                listemiz.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `actionbar activity` is deprecated.!

Comment: Ooops! didnt notice that just copy his code. My Bad :)

Comment: @Melvin man i almost wrote the same answer and saw yours before posting it , good job :)

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, some of which are given below:

- To do this you should remove all code from your `onClick()` and write everything in `onCreate()` method of your activity.
- Try this: `findViewById(R.id.button).performClick();`